# Android App won't run code inside of try block

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(wyvernBones); //"http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/3104-wyvern-bones"
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        fetched = false;
        progBox.show();
        while (!fetched) {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line.contains("Average Sell Offer")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progBox.dismiss();
                fetched = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above is the first approach I used.

```
public void getItem() throws Exception
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(wyvernBones); //"http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/3104-wyvern-bones"
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    fetched = false;
    progBox.show();
    while (!fetched) {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line.contains("Average Sell Offer")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progBox.dismiss();
            fetched = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After using the following code inside of a try catch block with no avail, I instead put it into a method.
During debugging, I realized the code inside the try/catch block wasn't even being processed/ran(?). What have I done wrong?

e: the first sample was attempted in the onCreate method, the second sample was called when a button was pressed.

Entire Code;

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

Button btn1;

ProgressDialog progBox;
Boolean fetched;
String line;

URL url;

String wyvernBones = "http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/3104-wyvern-bones";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progBox = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progBox.setIndeterminate(true);
    progBox.setTitle("Fetching Data..");

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(wyvernBones); //"http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/3104-wyvern-bones"
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        fetched = false;
        progBox.show();
        while (!fetched) {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line.contains("Average Sell Offer")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progBox.dismiss();
                fetched = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you use the code?

Comment: Sorry, in the onCreate method. Ill update accordingly.

Comment: this `while (!fetched) {` is an infinite loop (actually it is not because it is broken by the inevitable NPE)

Comment: Did you check your logcat?

Comment: Also check to make sure you are not trying to mess with the main thread.  Is there an NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: Updated my code; still doesnt work.

Comment: @KrisKrause Would that be cause by not adding a permission? If so, the permission exists in my manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment mentioned the "problem" without really describing it. You can't do `httpClient.execute` on the UI thread, which is where `onCreate` runs.

[android httpclient.execute exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240821/android-httpclient-execute-exception)

The reason you think the code is not executing but it appears to be doing so is that you `catch` the exception. Check your logcat, then read up on `AsyncTask`

EDIT:

You can also use a background thread if you are familiar with multi-threading and the benefits/pitfalls. That is actually how I usually do tasks because `AsyncTask` has it's own benefits/pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Would it be possible to run said code in a Thread(Runnable)?

Comment: Absolutely! I've modified my answer to reflect that.